# Subtracting values from an integer until a target reached

Tags: java

I am working on a problem in Java that features an adaptation of the partition problem. Effectively, a sequence of numbers of length 5 or more is entered into the command line, and if the sequence can be split into two equal parts, true is output, and if it cannot, false is given. It is important to note that the numbers in the sequence can't be rearranged.

I have found that a solution can be found by taking the sum of all the numbers in the sequence, then dividing it by 2 to find another integer value (I'll call it T2 for this purpose). If we subtract the numbers in the sequence in order from T2 and if it becomes equal to zero at any point, ie. T2 - "term 1" - "term 2" - ... - "term n" = 0, then we need to output true. I am unsure however how this can be implemented in Java. I have experimented a little with using different "for"and "while" loops but can't get it to meet the conditions I need to give the correct output.

If anyone could point me in the right direction of how to implement this process into Java I would be extremely grateful. Apologies for the terrible formatting of the question, I'm very new to the site. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *if the sequence can be split into two equal parts* - define "equal".

Comment: For example if the sequence was {1, 2, 3, 4, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4} and {10} would be equal parts as the sum of both is 10. Sorry, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: This is a simple loop. We could give you a solution, but you wouldn't learn anything. Try harder. Read the java tutorial about loops. Try with even simpler problems, like computing the sum of the elements of an array, for example. If you have some precise question about code you have written, then ask that question, and post your code.

Comment: I appreciate this but it's something I've been stuck on for several hours and was just looking for some pointing in the right direction. I am familiar with loops and have been experimenting with a number of ways of doing this but can't quite seem to get there.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you tried in these several hours? And what errors you have found with the code posted?

Comment: I am unsure of the formatting used on this site so I've put it into a pastebin link. https://pastebin.com/NXzEtzT6

Comment: It's not that hard. You paste the code, select it, press Ctrl-K or the code icon. You should be able to do that. And again. Post the complete and exact error you get, along with the code. The code should care about arguments. It should just hardcode an array, have a first loop to compute the sum, Then,once the sum is known, have a second loop to find the sequence. Respect the Java naming conventions. Don't use meaningless variable names like s, T, U or A.